# SQL query to parse a string and compare the value with today's date

Tags: mysql, sql, stringtokenizer

I have a data field with values: 2020Q3, 2020Q4, 2021Q1, 2021Q2, etc and I need to compare if Today's date > the data field value in SQL. For example, Today's date > 2020Q3 should return true. Today's date > 2020Q4 should return false.

I tried string tokenizer to parse and compare but no luck. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should have stored the date into the date column, as it would be easier to write sql to output the `2020Q3` format based on a field it could understand and simply process

Answer (score 0):

If you have a value like `'YYYY"Q"Q'`, you can get the start date of the quarter using:

```
select date(concat(left(yyyyq, 4), '-01-01')) + interval 3 * (right(yyyyq, 1) - 1) month
from (select '2020Q3' as yyyyq) t
```

And then add three months for the end date.  I'm not quite sure how you are interpreting `>`, but that information should give you what you need for the comparisons.